# Add columns to build history in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I would like to add extra columns to the build history sidebar that can be modified by user (comments,etc..).

Has anyone did something similar? or any suggestions how can it done easily?

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot add columns to the build history** without digging deeper into the Jenkins-internal layout engine.

The simplest solution to achieve what you want is to use the **"Edit Build Information"** menu item for a build. Users can add information there, and it's also possible to add HTML code with tables etc there, which can then look nicely in the build history.

It's not as interactive as what you're looking for, though, and it requires some discipline from your users to avoid that they destroy the build history format completely.

If you only need comments for *failed* builds, then the [Claim plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin) is a nice solution.